# It take some time for the method in Apex to become visible for the lightning component. What is a workaround here?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller

It take some time for the method in Apex to become visible for the lightning component. What is a workaround here?

I mean literally: I create an Apex controller, create a method in it, then I create a lightning component and in its client-side JavaScript controller perform a request to the Apex controller. I am getting an error that there is no such method in Apex controller. Then after some time (usually it is from instantly to a few hours period) the function becomes visible.

I see no point to post code here, I am just performing a standard lightning-component to Apex communication every time and I do not have a specific problem, just a recurring one.

In some cases I noticed (but I can not prove it) that if I change a return type of an Apex function, then try to call it from a lightning-component and then change the return type, the function is called successfully.

I just thought that maybe someone else is having the same problem and may suggest something here.

I just checked the `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance` in the **Session Settings** of the org where the problem takes place. And the caching was disabled all this time, hence the problem is different from the one described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144979/lightning-experience-how-to-prevent-the-display-of-obsolete-data/146605#146605).

The problem happens in a Developer Edition org.

I can not find the following setting: `Setup -> Lightning Components -> Enable Debug Mode checked`. I mean the `Enable Debug Mode checked` part. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: See/tried this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/146605/9853 ?

Comment: Sounds exactly like a caching problem, maybe with a slow compiler in the mix?

Comment: @battery.cord, what compiler are you talking about?

Comment: After you save a file, but before its cached, salesforce has to compile it, turning it into bytecode understood by the actual platform machines. The resulting code is cached for use by the org. See [this video](https://www.salesforce.com/video/303091/) for a detailed description of each step. If caching isn't enabled, its likely the org's resources are being shared (very likely if its a sandbox) and compiling/caching is delayed due to the volume of requests.

Comment: @battery.cord, so, are you proposing to try to enable caching here?

Comment: FYI, it is not a problem I have experienced. I work with Setup -> Session Settings -> Enable secure and persistent browser caching _unchecked_ (and Setup -> Lightning Components -> Enable Debug Mode _checked_). Perhaps the Salesforce instance you are working in has a problem.

Comment: I do a ton of Lightning and noticed something along these lines as well - Apex methods not appear after save. I'm on scratch orgs, medium sized codebase, so cacheing doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @KeithC, I can not find the `Setup -> Lightning Components -> Enable Debug Mode checked`, so I am updating the question to provide you with the information on it. If possible, check, please, what am I missing here that I do not find the `Enable Debug Mode checked`.

Comment: Just another data point that I have never experienced this either. Sounds to me like either the problem is being misinterpreted (i.e. the class did not really save) or there is an issue on the pod you are working in.....

Comment: @iloveseven Looks like that setup has improved and it is now (in Classic) Setup -> Developer -> Lightning Components -> Debug Mode. And +1 to Eric's suggestion to double check that the class did save e.g. double check that the new method is present via the Setup UI.

Comment: @KeithC, I am working through the Illuminated Cloud and after tweaking the class and not seeing the changes from the lightning-component I go to the developer console and check the changes there and they are present. Do you think this is not enough?

Comment: @iloveseven No that sounds enough. (The Setup UI is just the ultimate test because that is directly what is in the org.) By the way, I've been using VSCODE/SFDX with scratch orgs and found it productive; I have colleagues who love IlluminatedCloud though. though